# CHECK constraint to check substring matches other column (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to create a CHECK constraint to check that the first and the second elements of a barcode field match the data supplied in the project_code and center_code fields, eg.

```
+----------------+--------------+-------------+
|    barcode     | project_code | center_code |
+----------------+--------------+-------------+
| PP22-NY-1BCDE6 | PP22         | NY          |
+----------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I have tried using

```
barcode ~ ^[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{2}-[A-Z0-9]{6}$
```

Which works to some extent, however barcodes that do not precisely match the project_code and center_code would still match. How can I incorporate other field values in the CHECK constraint in PostgreSQL to do this?

Comment: Exactly what checks do you want to implement?  If you need to know the syntax, it's in the manual...  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html

Comment: `CHECK (substring(barcode from 1 for 8) = project_code || '-' || center_code || '-')`?

Comment: Aside from the constraint, if you have control of the database schema then another way to guarantee they match is to only store the barcode field, then replace the two _code fields with functions that return the appropriate substrings of barcode. Then you get the constraint for free and use less storage space too.

Comment: @MatBailie I did check the documentation but it wasn't clear to me (SQL beginner) that you could use string concatenation (`||`) in check constraints, thanks for clarifying
@Harun it would probably save some space, but the `_code` fields are set as foreign keys to two `_codes` tables to ensure that these match predefined values, I guess I could do the reverse with the barcode, but the issue there is that the last 6 character of the barcode are not stored in any other field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do:

```
constraint chk_t_barcode check (barcode like project_code || '-' || center_code || '-%')
```

If you wanted to be sure that the last six characters are alphanumeric:

```
constraint chk_t_barcode check (barcode ~ project_code || '-' || center_code || '-[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}')
```